# Android streaming live mic audio between two android devices via wifi

Tags: android, audio, audio-streaming

Guys im currently doing a project that when you talk to an android device it will send its audio output in another android device connected to each other through wifi.

Well i found this link helpful [Streaming voice between Android Phones over WiFi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238376/streaming-voice-between-android-phones-over-wifi?answertab=votes#tab-top), but my problem with this code, i can't even run the application. Can someone tell me the problem? and What premission should i indicate in my manifest? thanks

Comment: I also seen this link <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349987/stream-live-android-audio-to-server> but the receiver is ain't an android device, can i know the the exact source code for the receiver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i already found the answer just by tweaking the sampling rate and the minBufSize at 16000hz and a 4096 minBufsize

Comment: Can you help me because I am also looking for the same but unfortunately I am not able to run the application.