# Android- stream live mic audio from one device to multiple devices via WiFi

Tags: android, audio, audio-streaming

I am currently researching on building a live broadcasting module as a part of my app and this is the usecase: One user A will record his voice using the mic and this data has to be streamed to a server while the other devices should be able to receive this audio and play it.All of them will be connected to the same network. I would like to preferably use a server that is not java based. I have currently looked into the solutions provided in the following links:

[1]:    [Stream Live Android Audio to Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349987/stream-live-android-audio-to-server%3E)    [2]:    [Streaming voice between Android Phones over WiFi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238376/streaming-voice-between-android-phones-over-wifi?answertab=votes#tab-top)   [3]:    [Android streaming live mic audio between two android devices via wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21873753/android-streaming-live-mic-audio-between-two-android-devices-via-wifi)

I have also considered some 3rd part libraries but I do not wish to use them since they are expensive.

Comment: Lots more information needed...  What sort of quality and latency requirements do you have?  From your question, it sounds like someone will record, then upload, then it will be played back on the devices.  In any case, if they're connected to the same network, you should use multicast and skip your server entirely.

Comment: I am implementing a walkie talkie concept where when a person speaks the other person(s) should hear his voice in the background.

Comment: Make this easy... 16 kHz 8-bit PCM, sent in UDP over multicast.  You'll have ultra low latency, and good enough quality for voice.  They're all on the same network so the multicast will work.

Comment: Thanks for your solution @Brad. I have never tried using this before and I am not able to find enough references on how to implement this. Will you be able to give some links? I am currently trying with AWS to stream audio from my device to the storage and then receive the data on another device. But i am not able to get the result.

Comment: I like this idea. There's an app called AmpMe, which allows to play music on multiple phones simultaneously. There's also an app called SoundWire, which allows to use one phone as an audio speaker for all audio, but I'm not sure if it works between two phones. But there no service that I know of that sort of unifies these two the way you describe, and I'd like to have this functionality.