# Full duplex voice

Tags: android, audio, udp, audio-streaming

I want to create a full duplex voice transmission using UDP protocol but I get a lot of noise and delay and echo I will post the code and I will be grateful for any help thanks in advance I use some of the code in the 
[Streaming voice between Android Phones over WiFi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238376/streaming-voice-between-android-phones-over-wifi)

```
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private EditText ip;
private TextView streamingLabel;
private Button Call,Answer,End;

// public byte[] buffer;
public static DatagramSocket socket;
private int sendingport=50005;
private int recievingport=50006;//which port??
AudioRecord recorder;

//Audio Configuration.
private int sampleRate = 11025 ;      //How much will be ideal?
private int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;
private int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
AudioTrack speaker;
private boolean status = true;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ip = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText);
    streamingLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Call = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button);
    Answer = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button2);
    End = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button3);

    streamingLabel.setText("Press Start! to begin");

    Call.setOnClickListener (startListener);
    End.setOnClickListener (stopListener);
    Answer.setOnClickListener(receiveListener);
}

private final View.OnClickListener stopListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        status = false;
        recorder.release();
        Log.d("VS", "Recorder released");
    }

};
private final View.OnClickListener receiveListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        status = true;
       Log.d("Note","RecordAudio");
        startReceiving();
     RecordAudio t=new RecordAudio();
        t.execute();
    }

};

private final View.OnClickListener startListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        status = true;
        startStreaming();
        PlayAudio a=new PlayAudio();
        a.execute();

    }

};

public void startStreaming() {


    Thread streamThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {


                int minBufSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);
                DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
                Log.d("VS", "Socket Created");
                byte[] buffer = new byte[minBufSize*10];

                Log.d("VS","Buffer created of size " + minBufSize);
                DatagramPacket packet;

                final InetAddress destination = InetAddress.getByName(ip.getText().toString());
                Log.d("VS", "Address retrieved");


                recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,minBufSize);
                Log.d("VS", "Recorder initialized");
                //  speaker = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,(minBufSize*10),AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);



                recorder.startRecording();
                // speaker.play();

                while(status == true) {


                    //reading data from MIC into buffer
                    minBufSize = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                    Log.d("VS", "Reading");
                    //putting buffer in the packet
                    packet = new DatagramPacket (buffer,buffer.length,destination,sendingport);
                    Log.d("VS", "creating packet");
                    //   speaker.write(buffer, 0, minBufSize);
                    socket.send(packet);
                    //Arrays.fill(buffer, Byte.parseByte(null));

                }



            } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
                Log.e("VS", "UnknownHostException");
            }
            catch (Throwable t) {
                Log.e("AudioTrack", "Playback Failed");
            }
       /*    catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("VS", "IOException");
           }*/


        }

    });
    streamThread.start();
}
private class PlayAudio extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {

                DatagramSocket recievingsocket = new DatagramSocket(recievingport);
                Log.d("VR", "Socket Created");

                int minBufSize1 = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);

                byte[] buffer1 = new byte[minBufSize1*10];


                //minimum buffer size. need to be careful. might cause problems. try setting manually if any problems faced
                //  int minBufSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);

                speaker = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,(minBufSize1*10),AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

                speaker.play();
               while(status == true) {
                    try {


                        DatagramPacket packet1 = new DatagramPacket(buffer1,buffer1.length);
                        recievingsocket.receive(packet1);
                        Log.d("VR", "Packet Received");

                        //reading content from packet
                        buffer1=packet1.getData();
                        Log.d("VR", "Packet data read into buffer");

                        //sending data to the Audiotrack obj i.e. speaker
                        speaker.write(buffer1, 0, minBufSize1);
                        Log.d("VR", "Writing buffer content to speaker");
                     //   Arrays.fill(buffer1, Byte.parseByte(null));
                    } catch(IOException e) {
                        Log.e("VR","IOException");
                    }
                    catch(Throwable t){
                        Log.e("AudioTrack", "Playback Failed");
                    }
                }


            } catch (SocketException e) {
                Log.e("VR", "SocketException"+e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

}

public void startReceiving() {

    Thread receiveThread = new Thread (new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {

                DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(sendingport);
                Log.d("VR", "Socket Created");

                int minBufSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[minBufSize*10];


                //minimum buffer size. need to be careful. might cause problems. try setting manually if any problems faced
                //  int minBufSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);

                speaker = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,(minBufSize*10),AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

                speaker.play();
                while(status == true) {
                    try {


                        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);
                        socket.receive(packet);
                        Log.d("VR", "Packet Received");

                        //reading content from packet
                        buffer=packet.getData();
                        Log.d("VR", "Packet data read into buffer");

                        //sending data to the Audiotrack obj i.e. speaker
                        speaker.write(buffer, 0, minBufSize);
                        Log.d("VR", "Writing buffer content to speaker");
                      //  Arrays.fill(buffer, Byte.parseByte(null));
                    } catch(IOException e) {
                        Log.e("VR","IOException");
                    }
                    catch(Throwable t){
                        Log.e("AudioTrack", "Playback Failed");
                    }
                }


            } catch (SocketException e) {
                Log.e("VR", "SocketException"+e.getMessage());
            }


        }

    });
    receiveThread.start();
}
private class RecordAudio extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {


            int minBufSize1 = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);
            DatagramSocket sendingsocket = new DatagramSocket();
            Log.d("VS", "Socket Created");
            byte[] buffer1 = new byte[minBufSize1*10];

            Log.d("VS", "Buffer created of size " + minBufSize1);
            DatagramPacket packet1;

            final InetAddress destination = InetAddress.getByName(ip.getText().toString());
            Log.d("VS", "Address retrieved");


            recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat, minBufSize1);
            Log.d("VS", "Recorder initialized");
            //  speaker = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,(minBufSize*10),AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);


            recorder.startRecording();
            // speaker.play();

            while (status == true) {


                //reading data from MIC into buffer
                minBufSize1 = recorder.read(buffer1, 0, buffer1.length);
                Log.d("VS", "Reading");
                //putting buffer in the packet
                packet1 = new DatagramPacket(buffer1, buffer1.length, destination, recievingport);
                Log.d("VS", "creating packet");
                //   speaker.write(buffer, 0, minBufSize);
                sendingsocket.send(packet1);
               // Arrays.fill(buffer1, Byte.parseByte(null));

            }


        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.e("VS", "UnknownHostException");
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e("AudioTrack", "Playback Failed");
        }
       /*    catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("VS", "IOException");
           }*/

        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: Got any luck? i have to do a similar thing?

Comment: actually i solve this problem what is your problem in order to help you