# Voice chat over local or internet?

Tags: android

I was looking for a sample code for voice chat over local network. So I found it here :

[Streaming voice between Android Phones over WiFi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238376/streaming-voice-between-android-phones-over-wifi)

I couldn't leave a comment there. I have few question will you help me with it?

1. Should I make two separated project for each part??
2. Should i enter internet IP address? or local network ip address?? I tested with both didn't work!! why??

local ip was like 192.168.1.100
and internet ip : 188.213.158.120 on port 50005

Comment: is there any one have two android phone to test the App?

Comment: I have.. I am working on the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope works for you.

1_yes

2_local ip address