# Android : input data through 3.5mm jack

Tags: android

Can we send data to mobile through 3.5mm jack in and android mobile and write it to text file.
My prime motive is to send vibrational data to mobile and then process it. Constraint is that we cant use the accelerometer of mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem but I think data would have to be somehow coded and this would need some creativity but starting with this should be ok: [Android: Need to record mic input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959930/android-need-to-record-mic-input)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know 3.5 mm jack is for audio O/P. what do you mean by sending data to it?

Comment: Actually what i intend to do is acquire vibrational data and some how put it in android phone, through any means whether it be usb port or audio jack or anything,for further processing. If not 3.5mm jack..then any other alternative with as much as less any external hardware setup as possible.