# automate an app

Tags: android

Could anyone provide me with some tutorials that would help me in creating an app that senses the temperature,motion or voice of a person and starts automatically depending on the changes in these parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some piece of the app running to be able to sense the stimulus and respond to it.  One way to do that is to create a [service](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html) that runs in the background and monitors things.  Once you detect the criteria you can start the application with something like

```
Context ctx = getContext();
ctx.startActivity(new Intent(ctx, YourActivity.class));
```

There are many ways to read the sensors but you could start [with this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSensor/article.html)

One answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959930/android-need-to-record-mic-input) has information about recording from the microphone.

If this is your first app, I suggest you start with a tutorial that has a basic Android app in it and build it up, just writing some debug instead of starting the activity.  Once you have this going, you can pull the sensing code out into a separate service and start the activity after detection.  I also think there is some constraint that effectively means you have to have a user start the application the first time in order to start the service.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) that uses [Sensors](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html) and if something changes, they launch an Activity with an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html).