# Using MediaRecorder and NoiseSuppressor in Android

Tags: android, audio, microphone, mediarecorder, noise

I'm starting off a project experimenting with the Android microphone using code like this:

```
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

After that, a prepare() and start() to begin recording mic audio.

Trouble is, I'm trying to also add in some audio processing effects like NoiseSuppressor.  The API docs state that NoiseSuppressor is done with this:

```
 NoiseSuppressor create (int audioSession)
```

What is the appropriate method for initializing the recording stream and getting the audioSession for that stream?  I'm surprised to find that I cannot get the audioSession from the mediaRecorder.

Why do two approaches to setting up the audio stream exist?  I see the AudioRecord approach, but then the API docs suggest the above approach is preferred.

What gives?

Answer (score 5):

From Android Developers:

> To attach the NoiseSuppressor to a particular AudioRecord, specify the
>   audio session ID of this AudioRecord when creating the
>   NoiseSuppressor. The audio session is retrieved by calling
>   AudioRecord.getAudioSessionId() on the AudioRecord instance.

Which means `NoiseSuppressor` requires `audioSessionId` to create noise suppressor instance like this

```
val suppressor = NoiseSuppressor.create(
            recorder!!.audioSessionId)
```

if you look at [`getaudiosessionid`](https://developer.android.com/s/results/?q=getaudiosessionid)  reference then you will see that audio session  can only be created by **Media Player** or **Audio Recorder**.

**Hence you can't use `Noise Suppressor` along with `Media Recorder`.** However `Noise Suppressor` can be inserted by default in the capture path by the platform developers according to the `MediaRecorder.AudioSource` used.

Anyways if you still want to give Audio Recorder a try then I would say I already tried to enable NS in **Audio Recorder** & when I called `NoiseSuppressor.isAvailable()` it always returned **false**.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to be that MediaRecorder simply isn't suited for my type of processing.  I was looking to capture mic audio and do playback in real-time.  The better solution is to use AudioTrack and AudioRecord.

This topic discusses it nicely:

[Android: Need to record mic input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959930/android-need-to-record-mic-input)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to NoiseSuppressor then you have to use AudioManager along with MediaRecorder. For Noise Suppression please use below code :

// The following would take effect only on Jelly Bean and higher.

```
 audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
    audioManager.setParameters("noise_suppression=on");
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    Log.i("Trying to clean up audio because running on SDK " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);

    if (noise && NoiseSuppressor.create(getAudioSessionId()) == null) {
        Log.i("NoiseSuppressor not present :(");
    } else {
        Log.i("NoiseSuppressor enabled!");
    }

    if (gain && AutomaticGainControl.create(getAudioSessionId()) == null) {
        Log.i("AutomaticGainControl not present :(");
    } else {
        Log.i("AutomaticGainControl enabled!");
    }

    if (echo && AcousticEchoCanceler.create(getAudioSessionId()) == null) {
        Log.i("AcousticEchoCanceler not present :(");
    } else {
        Log.i("AcousticEchoCanceler enabled!");
    }
}
```