# Record audio and estimate pitch in a separate thread

Tags: android, multithreading, audiorecord, pitch-detection

I'm new to Android threads and I'm trying to figure out which is the correct/best approach to record and estimate pitch in a separate thread in Android.

I need to

- start recording/estimating from the UI thread
- receive the pitch from the background thread to the UI thread
- stop recording/estimating from the UI thread

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend you to take a look on the [AsyncTask's documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to know how to do something in an other thread detached of the UI thread.

Then, see [theisenp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7028963) to record something with the microphone.

**Note:** Remember to check if you need any kind of permission in your manifest, for example:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" ></uses-permission>
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: I read docs for AsyncTask, Handler, Thread, Executor, Service and related classes. I also read a lot of stuff on the web. Above all, this [article](http://techtej.blogspot.it/2011/03/android-thread-constructspart-4.html) helped me understanding differences between the various approaches to multithreading. I'd like to know from you how'd you implement a pitch detector using AudioRecord in a separate thread.