# Record sound of smartphone with visualizer in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, fft, visualizer

First of all, I've read a lot about this but only how to record Audio from the Media Player of the Smartphone.
What I need is to use the Visualizer class (or maybe there is another way?) to record the audio (especially the ringtone of the phone) and convert it with the getFFT() method. How can I achieve that? Hope someone can help me. I couldn't find something about that around the Internet.

Thank you!

Comment: This is an Android response for clarification about how Visualizer and getFFT work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720512/android-2-3-visualizer-trouble-understanding-getfft Does it help you somehow?

Comment: I guess this does not help. They are talking about how the FFT method works and the example is again how to record the Media Player output. I need the normal output of the Smartphone.